# how to check variable validity and how to send array of structure to function?

Tags: c, data-structures

I'm working in library system, I've a lot of things going on:(.  In `addBook` function I'm trying to add book information into Array of structure. First I don't know how to set a statement to check all the validity of title, author, isbn and others. I tried to write a statement but it wont work so I removed it! and didn't call the functions since I don't know how to make them work!  secondly I want to send the book information to a file so I can store them inside the file and sort alphabetically. whenever I try to send the array and check the txt file it print the address please help :(  I'm trying to keep it simple as possible as I can

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


#define MAX_ISBN 11
#define MIN_ISBN 9

#define MAX_YEAR  2021
#define MIN_YEAR 1500

#define MAX_DAY 31
#define MIN_DAY 1

#define MAX_MONTH 12
#define MIN_MONTH 1

#define MIN_ISBN 9
#define MAX_Title 80
#define MAX_Author 80

struct Book{

    int ISBN[MAX_ISBN], Edition[500], Year[MAX_YEAR],DD[MAX_DAY], MM[MAX_MONTH];
    char Title[MAX_Title];
    char Author[MAX_Author];
};

/*Check_Title function will check user input if it's a valid title or not! */
int Check_Title(char *Title){

    int valid_Title = 1;
    int len = 0;
    int i= 0;
    len = strlen(Title);

    for(i =0; i <len ; i++)
    {
        if( Title[i] == "#@$%^&*()}{[ ]")
            return 0;;

    }

    return 1;
}

/*Check_Author function will check user input if it's a valid Author name or not! */
int Check_Author(char *Author){

    int valid_Name = 1;
    int len = 0;
    int i= 0;
    len = strlen(Author);

    for(i =0; i <len ; i++)
    {
        if( !(isalpha(Author[i])) && (Author[i] != ' '))
        {
            valid_Name = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
    return valid_Name;
}

int Check_Date(int *DD, int *MM,int *YYYY){

    if(DD[MAX_DAY] > MAX_DAY || DD[MIN_DAY]< MIN_DAY)
        return 0;

    if(MM[MAX_MONTH] >31 || MM[MIN_DAY]<1)
        return 0;

    if(YYYY[MAX_YEAR]>MAX_YEAR || YYYY[MIN_YEAR]<MIN_YEAR)
        return 0;

    return 1; //if statement true return 1

    }
    int Check_ISBN(int *ISBN){

    if(ISBN[MAX_ISBN] > MAX_ISBN || ISBN[MIN_ISBN] < MIN_ISBN);
        return 0;

    return 1; //if ISBN VALID

}
// This function is used to check file existence, every time if it's called

//the following functions is user choice to either add a book, delete, view, and view by year -> Switch cases

void addBook(){

    system("cls"); //clearing black screen
    int Title_Validity = 0, Name_Validity = 0, ISBN_Validity, Date_Validity = 0,n;
    struct Book *insert = NULL;

    FILE* ptr = fopen("stored.txt","w");
                 if (ptr == NULL){
                    printf("Error opening the file! \n");
                               exit(1);}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

         printf("\n\t\t ========================================================================");
         printf("\n\t\t                            ADD NEW BOOK  ");
         printf("\n\t\t ========================================================================");

         printf("\n\n\t\t\tENTER YOUR DETAILS BELOW:");
         printf("\n\t\t\t---------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            printf("\t\tHow many Books would you like to insert? ");
            scanf("%d", &n);

            for(int i = 0; i<n; i++){

                insert = (struct Book*)calloc(n,sizeof(struct Book));
          //Inputing Title & Check Title validity
          //do{
          printf("\n\t\t\tBook Title  : ");
          fflush(stdin);
          fgets(insert[i].Title, MAX_Title, stdin);

         /*Title_Validity = Check_Title(&insert[MAX_Title].Title);
            if(Title_Validity){
            printf("\n\t\t *_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*__*_*_*_*_*__*_*_*_");
            printf("\t\t\t\t\t\t \t\t Invalid Input ! please try again! \n\t\t\t and make sure to not use         any digits or special characters! \n ");
            printf("\n\t\t *_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*__*_*_*_*_*__*_*_*_*_");
          }
          }while(Title_Validity);*/

          //Inputing Author
          printf("\n\t\t\tBook Author  : ");
          fflush(stdin);
          fgets(insert[i].Author, MAX_Author, stdin);


          //Inputing ISBN
          //do{
          printf("\n\t\t\tBook ISBN  : ");
          scanf("%d", &insert[i].ISBN);
         // fflush(stdin);
          //fgets(insert[i].ISBN, MAX_ISBN, stdin);
         /* ISBN_Validity = Check_ISBN(&insert[MAX_ISBN].ISBN);
                 if(ISBN_Validity == 0){
                 printf("\n\t\t *_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*__*_*_*_*_*__*_*_*_");
            printf("\t\t\t\t\t\t \t\t Invalid Input ! please try again! \n\t\t\t and make sure to not to not accedes the range 9~11! \n ");
            printf("\n\t\t *_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_*__*_*_*_*_*__*_*_*_*_");
          }

          }while(ISBN_Validity!=0);*/

          //Inputing Edition
          printf("\n\t\t\tBook Edition (only digits acceptable)  : ");
          scanf("%d", &insert[i].Edition);

          //Inputing Date
          printf("\n\t\t\tBook Date [DD MM YYYY]  : ");
          scanf("%d%d%d", &insert[i].DD,&insert[i].MM,&insert[i].Year);


       printf("\n\t\t ========================================================================");
         printf("\n\t\t       The book %s has been added to the library.", insert[i].Title );
         printf("\n\t\t ========================================================================");

            }
     
           //         
 
 
 
     Sort_Save(n,&insert[x].Title,&insert[x].Author,&insert[x].ISBN,&insert[x].Edition,&insert[x].DD,&insert[x].MM,&insert[x].Year);

       
    return;
}

void Sort_Save(int n,char Title[MAX_Title],char Author[MAX_Author], int ISBN[MAX_ISBN], int Edition[], int day[MAX_DAY], int month[MAX_MONTH], int year[MAX_YEAR]){

    int i;
    struct Book *st;
    FILE* fptr = fopen("sorted.txt", "w");
    if(fptr == NULL){
        printf("Error opening file! \n");
        exit(1);
    }
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){

       fprintf(fptr,"%s %s %d %d %d %d %d",st[i].Title,st[i].Author,st[i],st[i].ISBN,st[i].Edition,st[i].DD,st[i].MM,st[i].Year);
       fprintf(fptr,"\n");
    }
    printf("\n");

    fclose(fptr);
}
```

Comment: Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: "I don't know how to set a statement to check all the validity of title, author, isbn and others" - What are the constraints on these fields that would make them valid?

Comment: Moreover, what is your expected behavior, with specific examples?

Comment: I want to scan the input in addBook() function, while im scanning in for loop i want to call validity function of the each specific  input, ex. scan book title, call title validity function, the validity title function will check if the scanned book title is only string of characters bot special symbols.

Comment: Im expecting to add those info to a file and be sorted inside the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're asking the users how much books they want to add, you have to allocate the block of memory only once, best right after (before the loop) and certainly not again and again in the loop, where it gets initialized with '0' (zero, that's what calloc does).

And opening a file with the mode "w" truncates that file to zero length, i don't think that this is what you want. And why do you open it, when you do not access it, neither for reading nor for writing?

After scanning, you call the Sort_Save function with a bunch of useless parameters (where does the variable 'x' come from?). You should declare the function like this:

```
int sortSave(struct Book *books, size_t size)
```

and pass the allocated block (insert) with the specified size (n).

If you want to sort your library, then you should open the existing database for read first ("r"), then read all the stored values into an array, append the new data to that array, call 'qsort' (see man qsort), specify your compare function (where you specify by which parameter your library should be sorted), close the file, open it again in write mode ("w") and finally write all your (sorted) data into that file.

Do not to forget to flush and close the file, nor to free the allocated blocks of memory.

Edit:

As a hint, seperate code from design. First make sure your code works as expected, then add all the fancy stuff, best as a seperate function.